# Can NetLogo be run in parallel (like BehaviorSpace does) by only using built-in NetLogo API commands when controlling NetLogo experiments in Java?

Tags: java, netlogo

I am trying to run a series of experiments with NetLogo using the "Control API" feature with Java (as seen here https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Controlling-API), as I enjoy the extra flexibility in my project.  However, all the examples provided are done with a single set of experiment values, so its not obvious how to run a set of experiments with different values on different threads as the built in BehaviorSpace utility does.  When looking through the API, I couldn't seem to find this functionality.  Is this possible with NetLogo API alone, or is this something that I will have to manage directly now with Java, and if so, how do I ensure I get concurrent runs without opening separate instances of the JVM?

Here is my current attempt at controlling it in Java that I have yet to get to work--hence my impetus to have it work "for me" using NetLogo API.

```
public class NetLogoHOBMC implements Runnable {

public static void main(String [] args) {
Runnable trial1 = new NetLogoHOBMC("\"/Users/nqe/updateTable/dff/BMC_HO_mixed_onedist.nlogo\"", "\"Users/nqe/temp/\"", "1000", "100", "10", "1", "0", "1000");
Thread thread1 = new Thread(trial1);
thread1.setName("trial1");
System.out.println("Starting trial1.");
thread1.start(); 
}

public void run() {
    try {
        HeadlessWorkspace workspace = HeadlessWorkspace.newInstance();  
        //open the model
        workspace.open(model);
        ...}
```

For those interested, the above code seems to fail to actually open a JVM session upon calling HeadlessWorkspace.newInstance() despite me being able to get it to work as used in the aforementioned Controlling-API guide as part of a main function.

Comment: Can you give the actual output of the program you wrote? Is it throwing an exception? Just hanging? It looks like the right general direction to me.

Comment: @BryanHead Thanks for helping.  I managed to get the Java code to work, as I realized that the guide I was following (too blindly, I figure) set the Daemon property to true--which is not what I wanted to do to actually run a JVM process.  I don't fully understand their reasoning in their code, but that's why I ended up deleting all the Java parts from my question and keeping my original question focused solely on the NetLogo API portion which still might be useful to people who prefer interfacing with NetLogo's API.

Comment: I would like to help, but your question isn't clear. What doesn't work exactly? How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: you may want to create a worker class that implements runnable and then create as many as you need in your main thread.